Is It Possible to Create a PDF Viewer with Marker Functionality Like Google Maps in Flutter?
I’m working on a Flutter project where I want to implement a feature similar to Google Maps, but for a PDF document containing floor maps (like the picture attached below). Specifically, I want users to be able to:
Add markers at specific locations on the PDF.
Zoom in and out on the PDF while ensuring the markers remain accurately positioned.
Click on markers to potentially navigate to another screen or display information.
I’m using the Syncfusion PDF Viewer package, but I’m not sure how to achieve accurate marker positioning that responds well to zooming and panning.
My Questions:
Has anyone successfully implemented a similar feature? If so, could you share your approach or any code snippets?
What are the best practices for ensuring markers stay in the correct location while zooming in and out of the PDF?
Are there any libraries available that can help achieve this functionality, or do you recommend sticking with Syncfusion?
Are there any limitations or challenges I should be aware of when using the Syncfusion PDF Viewer for this purpose?
I have been trying to like this
floor plan map
class PdfMapWithAccurateMarkers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PdfMapWithAccurateMarkersState createState() => _PdfMapWithAccurateMarkersState();
}

class _PdfMapWithAccurateMarkersState extends State<PdfMapWithAccurateMarkers> {
  final PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
  List<PdfMarker> _markers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pdfViewerController.addListener(_updateMarkers);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pdfViewerController.removeListener(_updateMarkers);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateMarkers() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PDF with Markers'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SfPdfViewer.asset(
            'assets/sample.pdf',
            controller: _pdfViewerController,
            onDocumentLoaded: (PdfDocumentLoadedDetails details) {
              setState(() {});
            },
            onTap: (PdfTapDetails details) {
              // Add marker only if zoom level is greater than 1
              if (_pdfViewerController.zoomLevel > 1) {
                _addMarker(details.localPosition);
              }
            },
          ),
          ..._markers.map((marker) {
            Offset screenPosition = _getScreenPosition(marker);
            return Positioned(
              left: screenPosition.dx - 15,
              top: screenPosition.dy - 30,
              child: Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.red, size: 30),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addMarker(Offset tapPosition) {
    // Adding the marker with current zoom level and position
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(PdfMarker(tapPosition, _pdfViewerController.zoomLevel));
    });
  }

  Offset _getScreenPosition(PdfMarker marker) {
    // Get the current PDF view's position
    double zoomLevel = marker.zoomLevel;
    double pdfViewWidth = _pdfViewerController.getPdfPageSize(marker.pageNumber).width * zoomLevel;
    double pdfViewHeight = _pdfViewerController.getPdfPageSize(marker.pageNumber).height * zoomLevel;

    // Calculate the screen position based on the zoom level and marker position
    double x = (marker.position.dx * zoomLevel) - (pdfViewWidth / 2);
    double y = (marker.position.dy * zoomLevel) - (pdfViewHeight / 2);

    return Offset(x, y);
  }
}

class PdfMarker {
  final Offset position;
  final double zoomLevel;
  final int pageNumber;

  PdfMarker(this.position, this.zoomLevel) : pageNumber = 1; // Update this logic based on the actual page if needed
}


https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-widgets/issues/1958
